# Polymer web component not working with asp.net core 2.0 Razor pages

Tags: polymer, asp.net-core-2.0, polymer-2.x, razor-pages

I have created a very simple ASP.NET Core 2.0 project and selected the new Razor Page template then I removed everything from homepage and added Paper-button web component in order to use it following is code for my `Index.cshtml`:

```
page
@model IndexModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home page";
}

<paper-button raised>My Button</paper-button>
```

Then I added import statements for this component in my file `Layout.cshtml` as follows this is how its head looks like now:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, 
    initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes">
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - DineAlong</title>

    //notice the following script for pollyfills and then the import for paper-button
    <script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js">
    </script>
    <link rel="import" href="/bower_components/paper-button/paper-button.html">
    <environment include="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    </environment>
    <environment exclude="Development">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          asp-fallback-test-class="sr-only" asp-fallback-test-property="position" asp-fallback-test-value="absolute" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.min.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    </environment>
</head>
```

After running html page only shows text `MyButton` and doesn't display the paper-button at that place.

Note: I have `bower_components` folder alongside `Layout.cshtml` and `Index.cshtml`, i.e: within the **Pages folder** so the reference import in Layout file should work fine.

Following is the errors in the **console** I can see the error but I don't know why it is happening.

[image: error console]

Folder Structure:

[image]

Comment: Can you post your folder/project structure?

Comment: @Ofisora Please see the updated question

Comment: Can you remove first \ from the \bower_components... or add . (dot) before it and check again?

Comment: yeah ive tried that, that doesnt help either

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the directory to under the wwwroot folder (probably under lib).
The Pages directory is only referenced by the MVC routing engine and not the web server.

For example I added Font Awesome to my project and can reference it like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
```

[image]

Comment: What is your path when under wwwroot? Notice how my path is relative to the root.

Comment: yeah I also used the same path as you because I have location same as u I put the folder in lib under root, I think problem is polymer itself, it can only be used in polymer web apps with polymer serve or polymer build. though m not sure about that